# C# .NET Standard - Expression tree value not parsed as expected

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Currently we're working on a project with expression trees, but we noticed a small bottleneck during our NUnit tests.

Whenever we directly pass a value within the expression, it's parsed as expected (see Expression_Success() in code example below). But whenever we pass a variable containing the value, we get an unexpected result (see Expression_Fail() in the code example below).

```
 [Test]
 public void Expression_Fail()
 {
     var username = "test";
     Where(x => x == username);
     // Result Where expression: {x => (x == value(ORMNUnit.ORMCollectionTests+<>c__DisplayClass5_0).username)}
    // Why is not "test" shown here?
 }

 [Test]
 public void Expression_Success()
 {
     Where(x => x == "test");
     // Result Where expression: {x => (x == "test")}
     // The value "test" is shown as expected.
 }

 public void Where(Expression<Func<object, bool>> expression)
 {
            
 }
```

So our question: why is the value not passed directly?

Comment: Because you are "closing" around a variable (`username`). When you *close* a variable, a hidden class is generated (`<>c__DisplayClass5_0` in this case) where the variable is kept.

Comment: when it comes to expression tree, the 2 ways produce completely different expressions. The first one considers the placeholder a variable expression whereas the second one considers it a constant expression. This is definitely an error in your `Where` implementation or simply it's not designed/implemented to support variable expression.

Comment: So is there a way, to keep the same or similar syntax where the actual value would be passed?

Comment: If you want I prepared a [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI6oFEAPABwCcBTAZyswHtsqBuWWbAQwFtqT2BjCogDyAJQCyAOQCu2TABdEAb1gBIEAGZkYYeIDCdADYGKfOfWwAVanKpLVazSAAsiYuWq0GAfQBi7TAYAFACUdjAqEQBu7GSIUlQUZBzciAC8iABEctYZLOERAOoAFokUgURpAHyIFanp8YnJFMF5EQC+rPkayC5ulDTmXgDKUnwCNCFhESrFpeVVNWnpWTkt9h0w9t3OiLOUgX0e5ogAPMgArKeIdABGAFYmcgA0iDd0hoiV1RSk/Z7YoWU+Q2Kg2bSAA==) so you can check what happens

Comment: Ahh thanks, that's interesting. So, we would have to create something so it uses a Expression.Constant.

Comment: And no, there is no way. Closures are a central part of LINQ. You can't say "disable linq". You could perhaps create an expression tree transformer that transforms the "closed" parts to constants, but it is a big "perhaps", a big work, and you wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: Alright, thanks for the insights!

Comment: @Albi I remember that I've done something like in this scenario to actually evaluate the variable expression and turn it into a constant expression. (it requires some expression visitor ...). I'm pretty sure that it's possible. However it has been quite a long time so sorry no help here. You can google and find out more about it yourself, it's quite interesting to research it if you want to learn more about expression tree.

Comment: You can write an expression visitor that performs a bottom up analysis and then does a partial evaluation over the closed over variables... evaluates them to constants , translating the expression in the process. It's tricky, but I did something like that for a custom ORM... Though without knowing what you're doing overall, it's likely overkill.

Comment: Not mine, but here's a pretty complete version of that: https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit/blob/master/src/IQToolkit/PartialEvaluator.cs

Comment: @KingKing thanks :) I find expression trees very interesting, so will definitely continue to research it.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Me and a friend are working on a custom built ORM right now (for learning purposes) for the past year, but we've only written unit tests so far where we directly put in the values, not through variables. Causing us not to notice it before, thanks for the Github link, we'll have a look and continue our research and hopefully create an expression visitor.

Comment: I wrote about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/september/net-development-expression-trees-in-visual-basic-and-csharp#closed-over-variables); look at the first example in the image. (Really frustrated at how they messed up the formatting...) You can see views of expression trees similar to the image using the [Expression Tree Visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer) that I've written.

Comment: We still wanted to say thanks, through your inputs we were able to solve our problem.